# kendoWindow correct library usage

Tags: kendo-window

in my application I am using:

"kendo.web.min"

"angular-kendo"

"kendo.common.min.css"

"kendo.bootstrap.min.css"

I want to add a popup window to my app, so I'm trying to follow this demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index

But when I'm trying to add "kendo.all.min.js" in order to use the window, the window pops up but the rest of the application doesn't work.

When I remove "kendo.all.min.js", the "kendoWindow " returns as "undefined"

```
var window = jQuery("#windowTests");
window.kendoWindow({....                <==== returns "undefined"
```

How can I use the kendoWindow in my application?

Thank you!

Comment: have you checked the following link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
According to that, "kendo.all.min.js" should have been enough for all I need.
But it crashes my app.
Could it be versions issue?

Comment: If you can provide a code sample of what you are trying to do then it may help in giving you a more appropriate answer.